# Seek Bar Progress is not updating after Activity/Fragment relaunch

Tags: android, android-fragments, seekbar, android-seekbar

I was **customized android default seek bar** to show in vertically and using in fragments go get some feedback from user.

After first launch it is showing properly. But Once I submitted my first feedback I am relaunching the activity with fragments which contains my customized Vertical Seek Bar.

At that time thumb in Vertical Seekbar is coming to "0" but progress is not coming to "0" and showing some progress. :(

Below i am adding my Vertical Seek bar code please suggest me if i missed any thing .

```
public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {
    private int mLastProgress = 0;

    private OnSeekBarChangeListener mOnChangeListener;

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    }

    public synchronized int getMaximum() {
    return getMax();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    c.rotate(-90);
    c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);
    super.onDraw(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (mOnChangeListener != null) {
            mOnChangeListener.onStartTrackingTouch(this);
        }
        setPressed(true);
        setSelected(true);
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        int progress = getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight());

        // Ensure progress stays within boundaries
        if (progress < 0) {
            progress = 0;
        }
        if (progress > getMax()) {
            progress = getMax();
        }
        setProgress(progress); // Draw progress
        if (progress != mLastProgress) {
            // Only enact listener if the progress has actually changed
            mLastProgress = progress;
            if (mOnChangeListener != null) {
            mOnChangeListener.onProgressChanged(this, progress, true);
            }
        }

        onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
        setPressed(true);
        setSelected(true);
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (mOnChangeListener != null) {
            mOnChangeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(this);
        }
        setPressed(false);
        setSelected(false);
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        setPressed(false);
        setSelected(false);
        break;
    }
    return true;
    }

    public synchronized void setMaximum(int maximum) {
    setMax(maximum);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarChangeListener onChangeListener) {
    this.mOnChangeListener = onChangeListener;
    }

    public synchronized void setProgressAndThumb(int progress) {
    setProgress(progress);
    onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
    if (progress != mLastProgress) {
        mLastProgress = progress;
        if (mOnChangeListener != null) {
        mOnChangeListener.onProgressChanged(this, progress, true);
        }
    }
    }

    public synchronized void setMyProgress(int progress) {
    setProgress(progress);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution for my problem.
In .xml while creating vertical seekBar I used **android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek"** but in seek.xml i forgot to declare titles as

```
item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress",
item android:id="@android:id/background" and
```

item android:id="@android:id/progress".